# Passing Dynamic Data Between Two Controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, controller

I am looking to pass an item from a controller's $scope element (in this case the 'header' and 'content') to a page that is redirected-to upon a click.

The way it is currently set up is as follow:
- Page #1 loads the masterArray, displaying all elements 
- User then clicks on a button which is linked with the 'href' attribute
- When user clicks an href button, the new page (Page #2) is displayed.

My Question: How can I pass the 'header' and 'content' onto Page #2 and ensure that only the associated header/content (based on the link that is clicked) are mapped and displayed?

The code below is for the main page with all the data dynamically being displayed

```
app.controller("SomeController", function ($scope, $window) {
$scope.masterArray = [{
    title: "MainTitle",
    segments: [{
        title: "SubTitle",
        articles: [{
            header: "Article1Header",
            content: "SomeContent",
            href: "http://uniqueURL1.com"
        }, {
            header: "Article2Header",
            content: "SomeContent",
            href: "http://uniqueURL2.com"
        }, {
            header: "Article3Header",
            content: "SomeContent",
            href: "http://uniqueURL3.com"
        }, {
            header: "Article4Header",
            content: "SomeContent",
            href: "http://uniqueURL4.com"
        }]
    }

   }]
}];
```

Page #1

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
<div class="section">
<div class="segment" ng-repeat="m in shownArray">
    <div ng-repeat="s in m.segments" ng-if="m.segments">
        <h4 ng-show="filtered.length">{{s.title}} ({{filtered.length}})</h4>
        <div template="basic" ng-repeat="a in s.articles|articleFilter:query as filtered" is-open="a.isOpen">
            <h2 ng-bind-html="a.header | highlight:query"></h2>
            <div>
                <p ng-bind-html="a.content | highlight:query"></p>
                <a class="button button-primary" ng-href="{{a.href}}">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Page #2 (Desired Result)

```
<div>
<h2>//DISPLAYS ASSOCIATED 'header'</h2>
<h3>//DISPLAYS ASSOCIATED 'content'</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a single page app? Do the URLs navigate to different states?

Comment: @vinays84 this is not a single page app; However the URLs share the same domain and are under the same ng-app directive

Comment: Angular allows for passing data between states in a single-page app. As the links are new page requests, you would have to pass the data (`header` and `content`) as URL parameters (e.g. http://uniqueURL1.com?header=Article1Header&content=SomeContent), then parse them out.

Comment: @vinays84 is there a way to access the header attribute within the scope object? (i.e., `uniqueURL1.com?header=$scope.masterArray.segments.articles.header`)? I have tried searching but no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use URL Params, use [`$location.search`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search):

```
$rootScope.header = $location.search().header;
```

You can also use [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeParams) if you prefer to build your URL differently.

Both would require you to properly build `ng-href`:

```
ng-href="{{a.href+'?header='+a.header+'&content='+a.content}}"
```

If your architecture allows it, consider a single page app, in which you'd configure states with [`$stateProvider`](http://ivanproskuryakov.github.io/publications/AngularJS-routeProvider-and-stateProvider/#stateprovider) in your `config()` then use `ui-sref` to access them in your HTML.

Comment: Your second suggestion worked for my purposes. Thanks!